# function works outside of object will not work when called inside an object

Tags: jquery, mustache

I am trying to inject my page when it loads with a template using mustache. If i call my function to grab and inject the DOM with this data outside of 
the portfolio{} object it works perfectly fine and the HTML is injected on page and data is displayed correctly. but if i try to place my function inside of the portfolio{} object and call the function it will not work. This makes no since to me what so ever and i am getting quite frustrated with it. If anyone knows what might be causing this and how to fix i would be very grateful.

i am able to call the data from within the portfolio object and it works so i know it has nothing to do with the structure of my data.

I get no errors to help debug either.

THIS WORKS:

```
var portfolio = {
    projects: { 
        "proj": [
            {
                id:"1",
                title:"Heller Recipes",
                description:"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.google.com",
                genre:"web-app",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/heller-recipes/thumb.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                title:"3D Animation",
                description:"Created using 4D Cinema Max, a 3d anitmation program that allows you to create realistic renderings and animations.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.google.com",
                genre:"3d",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/4dmax.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
 };
$('body').on('click', '.logo', function(){
    var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
    var html =  Mustache.to_html(template, { "proj" : portfolio.projects.proj });
    $('.portfolio-wrapper').html(html);
});
```

THIS DOESN'T:

```
var portfolio = {
    projects: { 
        "proj": [
            {
                id:"1",
                title:"Heller Recipes",
                description:"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.google.com",
                genre:"web-app",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/heller-recipes/thumb.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                title:"3D Animation",
                description:"Created using 4D Cinema Max, a 3d anitmation program that allows you to create realistic renderings and animations.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.google.com",
                genre:"3d",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/4dmax.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    init: function(){
        var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
        var html =  Mustache.to_html(template, { "proj" : portfolio.projects.proj });
        $('.portfolio-wrapper').html(html);
    }
}
portfolio.init();
```

Comment: Your second example isn't even valid JavaScript. You should be getting console errors.  `portfolio.init` looks like an object, but contains procedural code. Should `init` be a function instead? i.e. `init: function() { ... your code  ... }`. If so, when is `init` called? Somewhere `portfolio.init()` should happen.

Comment: Sorry, i had to strip my function for this post and pasted it down wrong. it should be good to go now. I get no errors on my side.

Comment: Not sure why i am getting down voted for this question??

Comment: Suggest you create a simplified demo that replicates problem. Code shown is invalid as mentioned above

Comment: I changed the code since then. is it still not valid?

Comment: yes... init is invalid object that should be a function. You try to call it as function but haven't created as function

Comment: So i did a bad job at porting my code. if i were to of copied straight from file it would of been valid but way too much code. I have fixed the problem and ran both with lint and get no errors.  I can't create an example cause the places like jsFiddle and codepen don't supply mustache as an extension from what i have seen.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller: You can import external resources in jsFiddle and in Stack Snippets.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with inside/outside the object. You're not really comparing like with like here. In the first set of code, initialisation takes place in response to a later user event (clicking a logo). In the second, initialisation is attempted immediately, which, it would seem, is too early in the page's life.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `portfolio` from within `init` by name, because it doesn't quite exist yet. Try referring to `portfolio` with an alias to `this` (being `portfolio`), in case Mustache is clobbering `this` somehow):

```
var portfolio = {
    projects: { /* omitted */ },
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
        var html =  Mustache.to_html(template, { "proj" : self.projects.proj });
                                                       // ^ use "self"
        $('.portfolio-wrapper').html(html);
    }
}
portfolio.init();
```

Here's a simple example of this in action:

```js
var sampleObject = {
    property1: 'Hello, World!',
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        alert(self.property1); 
    }
}

sampleObject.init();
```

Comment: I posted a new post with valid code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754384/why-does-this-function-not-work-inside-of-an-object-but-basically-the-same-funct

Comment: And you don't receive ANY JS errors anywhere? Are you using the browser's debugger? At what point does this code run (`<head>`, domready, etc.)? The sample code above works; so should yours.

Comment: No i dont recieve any errors. i am using chromes web inspector

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller: You mean the F12 tools, "Console" tab, right? That's where JS errors would be displayed.

Comment: Correct. I use the Console all the time for debugging. that is what is so frustrating with this problem

Comment: I made one slight adjustment to the code above. Care to give that a try?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `portfolio.init()` line, does it get hit? If so, step through the code. See what `portfolios.projects.proj` is in that function (or one of the variants from my code). If not, then you have an error outside of this code that you'll need to track down first.

Comment: if i console.log portfolio.projects.proj it return a bunch of objects like you would expexct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71834/discussion-between-c-and-travis-michael-heller).